# Getting values from multiple Firebase database references in one cardView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am developing an app which requires me to get reference from two Firebase database references in one cardview. Below is the model of the cardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/action_setup"
            android:id="@+id/dPicture"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="Username"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/posted_username"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:elevation="10dp">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/posted_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@color/Orange"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="Post Title..."
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/posted_title"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Summary..."
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="300"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:id="@+id/posted_sharing"/>



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and this is how the database look like in Firebase

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "1" : {
      "image" : "http://something.com/something",
      "name" : "person 1"
    },
    "2" : {
      "image" : "http://someone.com/someone",
      "name" : "person 2"
    }
  },
  "posts" : {
    "post 1" : {
      "content" : "test content 1",
      "dPicture" : "http://something.com/something",
      "picture" : "http://postimage.com/postimage",
      "title" : "test title 1",
      "uid" : 1,
      "username" : "person 1"
    },
    "post 2" : {
      "content" : "test content 2",
      "dPicture" : "http://someone.com/someone",
      "picture" : "http://postimage2.com/postimage2",
      "title" : "test title 2",
      "uid" : 2,
      "username" : "person 2"
    }
  }
}
```

And the Activity code is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mPostedList;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseSharings;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mDatabaseSharings = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        mDatabaseSharings.keepSynced(true);

final String uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();


        //bring user to login activity when auth-state is null

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            }
        };




//keep users logged in
        mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

        mPostedList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.posted_list);
        mPostedList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mPostedList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();


        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        //your adapter
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostedModel, PostedModelViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostedModel, PostedModelViewHolder>(

                PostedModel.class, R.layout.posted_row, PostedModelViewHolder.class, mDatabaseSharings
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PostedModelViewHolder viewHolder, PostedModel model, int position) {


                        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                        viewHolder.setDPicture(getApplicationContext(), model.getDPicture());
                        viewHolder.setSummary(model.getSummary());
                        viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
                        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());


                final String post_key = getRef(position).getKey();





                viewHolder.mView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                        Intent delete_intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DeleteActivity.class);
                        delete_intent.putExtra("blog_id", post_key);
                        startActivity(delete_intent);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent comment_intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, CommentActivity.class);
                        comment_intent.putExtra("blog_id", post_key);
                        startActivity(comment_intent);
                    }
                });


            }
        };
        mPostedList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mPostedList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    }

    public static class PostedModelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{



        View mView;

        public PostedModelViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);





            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title){


    TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.posted_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }
        public void setDPicture(Context ctx, String dPicture){

            ImageView post_dPicture = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.dPicture);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(dPicture).into(post_dPicture);
        }


        public void setSummary (String summary){

            TextView post_summary = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.posted_sharing);
            post_summary.setText(summary);
        }
        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image){
           ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.posted_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);


        }
        public void setUsername (String username){
           TextView post_username = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.posted_username);
            post_username.setText(username);
        }

    }


}
```

Of course there is the PostedModel.class which is the getters and setters class for it

```
public class PostedModel {
    private String title;
    private String summary;
    private String image;
    private String dPicture;


    private String username;

    public PostedModel(){}

    public PostedModel(String title, String summary, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.image = image;
        this.dPicture = dPicture;
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getDPicture() {
        return dPicture;
    }

    public void setDPicture(String dPicture) {this.dPicture = dPicture;}

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {this.title = title;}

    public String getSummary() {
        return summary;
    }

    public void setSummary(String summary) {
        this.summary = summary;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

Now as you can see I have a posting activity that pass both the username as well as the image value from the "Users" database to the "posts" database child (dPicture). However, when a user update his/her username, only the values from the "Users" database are changed and not from existing "posts"

I figure the most efficient way to do this is to populate the viewholder with data from the two database references, connecting both using the user's unique id which is the key in the "Users" database and as child (uid) in the "posts" database but I don't know how to do it... I am attaching a snapshot of the database screenshot with boxes to illustrate in case I am confusing people with my subpar technical language

[image: here]

So the goal is to get the red boxed data and paired it with green boxed data.

Many thanks for all helps beforehand!

**Edit:**
I don't know if I am on the right track with this... So after researching I think the right way to do it is using a valueEventListener for the Database that I want to get data from inside the adapter class...

So far I got this

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostedModel, PostedModelViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PostedModel, PostedModelViewHolder>(

                PostedModel.class, R.layout.posted_row, PostedModelViewHolder.class, mDatabaseSharings
        ) {
            //calling the value from the Summary.java class
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final PostedModelViewHolder viewHolder, final PostedModel model, final int position) {
mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.getKey().toString() == mDatabaseSharings.child("uid").toString()){
        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
        viewHolder.setDPicture(getApplicationContext(), model.getDPicture());
    }

        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
        viewHolder.setSummary(model.getSummary());
        viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

But I am getting the key instead of the value passed haha

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two array list say ArrayList abc,def. Then after you fetch the data from Users node, write assign username and image like abc.username. Right after this, fetch data from Posts node and do the same thing for the rest of the data. Then at the end of both the functions,write def.add(abc); I think this should do the job.

Comment: hi @Ambuj thanks for the comment. Hmmm I think I should use valueEventListener because that seems to be how everyone else is doing it... I just don't know how to implement it correctly...

Comment: I am trying to do this here but it is not working : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259345/combining-two-arrays-of-model-class-type-firebase-android